# How to create a global function in redux Slice?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, redux, redux-toolkit

I am making a redux slice which will store the following states
1.open : boolean
2.name : string
(these are meant to open targeted menu only)

Here is my redux slice for the same.

```
import { createAsyncThunk, createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { dialogSlice } from "../../dialog/dialogSlice";

export interface TestState {
    open : boolean;
    name : string;
}

const initialState : TestState = {
    open : false,
    name : ''
}


export const handleOpenDialog = createAsyncThunk(
    "test/handleOpenDialog",
    (name : string, { dispatch }) => {
     dispatch(
      testSlice.actions.setOpenDialog({
        open : true,
        name 
      })
     )
     console.log(name)
    }
);

export const testSlice = createSlice({
    name : 'testDialog',
    initialState,
    reducers : {
     setOpenDialog : ( state, action ) => {
      state.open = true;
      state.name = action.payload
     }
    }
});

export const { setOpenDialog } = dialogSlice.actions;
```

I am using this slice into my component having 2 menus as under
(**MY COMPONENT**)

```
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "../../Redux/reduxStore";

export default function MenuComponents () {

// importing slice
const { open, name } = useSelector((state : RootState) => state.testDialog );
const dispatch = useDispatch();

return (
<Grid container spacing = {2}>
            <Grid item xs = {6}>
              <Typography variant = {'subtitle2'}>Dialog 1</Typography>
              <IconButton 
               onClick = {() => dispatch(handleOpenDialog('menuA'))}
              ><OpenInBrowser /></IconButton>

              <Menu open = { name === 'menuA' && open } >
                <MenuItem>Option A</MenuItem>
                <MenuItem>Option B</MenuItem>
                <MenuItem>Option C</MenuItem>
                <MenuItem>Option D</MenuItem>
                <MenuItem>Option E</MenuItem>
              </Menu>
            </Grid>

            <Grid item xs = {6}>
              <Typography variant = {'subtitle2'}>Dialog 2</Typography>

              <IconButton 
               onClick = {() => dispatch(handleOpenDialog('menuB'))}
               ><OpenInBrowser /></IconButton>
 
               <Menu open = { name === 'menuB' &&  open } >
                 <MenuItem>Option A</MenuItem>
                 <MenuItem>Option B</MenuItem>
                 <MenuItem>Option C</MenuItem>
                 <MenuItem>Option D</MenuItem>
                 <MenuItem>Option E</MenuItem>
               </Menu>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
)}
```

The problem is on clicking the Iconbuttons of either of the menus, none is opening. I want to open the targeted menus by using "name" of type "String" as a specification parameter (as i defined into my asyncThunk ( handleOpenMenu).

**I don't want to write the locaState wherever I need menus into my components.
So I want to use a single redux slice to open/close only the targeted menus.
But it's not working , i don't know why (Maybe I am writing the incorrect logic, or maybe I am missing something into my testSlice file)?**

All suggestions are highly welcomed

Comment: I can't find any obvious mistake, but it sure looks weird that you're using `createAsyncThunk` for a plain (non-async) action. Have you tried not doing that?

Comment: I found a solution for this. Yes, your are right I shouldn't be using the createAsyncThunk for a plain (local function) , which has nothing to do with the api. I just want to know, how could I define the complete functions inside of redux slice?

Comment: What do you mean by define complete functions inside the slice? The action is already created by createSlice, you can dispatch it in your component.